# Restart While Loop With Keypress

Tags: python, while-loop, keypress, restart

I am looking to restart a while loop with a keypress after it has been broke out of using the same key. Basically I am looking to make while loop that can be toggled on and of by a keypress. My code so far stops the loop with a keypress, but I have no idea how to start it again.

```py
import keyboard
from time import sleep

key = "right shift"

while True:
    print("Running")
    sleep(0.5)
    if keyboard.is_pressed(key):
        break
```

I would describe the things I've tried here but I honestly have no idea.

Edit: Sorry for not being clear enough in the first place, but this is what I'm looking for:

> If you wanted the loop to restart, then put another while loop around
>   the current one, and put a line inside that one that waits for a
>   keypress before it moves on to the inner loop.

I have done what Kyle recommended and it's working quite well, except for the fact that you have to hold the key to get it to stop. I believe it can be fixed with timings, here's what I have so far:

```
import keyboard
from time import sleep

key = "right shift"

while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed(key):
        while True:
            print("Running")
            sleep(0.5)
            if keyboard.is_pressed(key):
                    sleep(1)
                    break
```

Comment: wait, do you want it to be toggled, or restarted?

Comment: Make your loop in a function, restarting would be executing the function again.

Comment: @Axium toggled would be the correct word. When the key is pressed the loop stops, when it is pressed again it starts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`keyboard`](https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/) module has more features allowing different hooks/blockers.

Just use `keyboard.wait(key)` to block the control flow until `key` is pressed:

```
import keyboard
from time import sleep

key = "right shift"

while True:
    print("Running")
    sleep(0.5)
    if keyboard.is_pressed(key):
        print('waiting for `shift` press ...')
        keyboard.wait(key)
```

Sample interactive output:

```
Running
Running
Running
waiting for `shift` press ...
Running
Running
Running
Running
Running
waiting for `shift` press ...
Running
Running
Running
...
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to run the while loop until the user presses the key, then break to go do other things in your code, until the key is pressed again.

One option would be to register a keyboard event handler, so that any time a key is pressed, regardless of where you are in the script (as long as it is still running) some handler function will get called.

Then put the while loop inside a function, and have that function get called by the keyboard event handler. The function should start by disabling / un-registering the event handler, then re-register it immediately before exiting. This way the function won't get called again while it is already running, but will respond again after it is done.

If you just want to pause the loop, you can put another while loop inside the if block that waits for a key to be pressed before it lets the outer loop continue.

If you wanted the loop to restart, then put another while loop around the current one, and put a line inside that one that waits for a keypress before it moves on to the inner loop.

Edit: Since it looks like you want the middle one, here's an example using basically the technique you are already using:

```
import keyboard
from time import sleep

key = "right shift"

while True:
    print("Running")
    sleep(0.5)
    if keyboard.is_pressed(key):
        # May need a delay here to prevent it from immediately continuing
        while True:    # Will stop the loop until you press again
            # Definitely put a delay here. Your CPU will thank you
            if keyboard.is_pressed(key): # Check if key is pressed again
                break;  # Get out of inner loop
        continue    # Go back to beginning of outer loop
                    # The continue is optional if this is the end of the loop
```

Edit 2: Example for the last one (although if you include the `continue` in the first example I gave it will have a similar effect)

```
import keyboard
from time import sleep

key = "right shift"

while True:
    while True:
        print("Running")
        sleep(0.5)
        if keyboard.is_pressed(key):
            break # Gets you out of the original loop
    # Put this at the end of the inner loop 
    # if you don't want to have to hit the key to start
    while True:    # Will stop the loop until you press again
        # Definitely put a delay here. Your CPU will thank you
        if keyboard.is_pressed(key): # Check if key is pressed again
                    break;  # Get out of inner loop
```

Comment: Damn, I'm sorry for the late reply, the last option is exactly what I'm looking for. I hope you didn't waste too much time on this code

Comment: I updated the answer to include another example, and added a comment about the delay that @Code-Apprentice suggested. If you use a small delay, it's not super noticeable to the user but makes a huge difference to how much CPU time your program will try to use. There may also be a version of the keyboard.is_pressed() function that can block until a key is pressed.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to have a flag:

```
go = True
while True:
  if go:
    print('Running...')
  sleep(0.5)
  if keyboard.is_pressed(key):
    go = not go
```

However, this isn't a very good way to code such things because your program takes complete control of the processor. When `go` is `False`, this is called a "busy wait". Instead, you should learn about event handling as Kyle describes in his answer.